# Facebook like button adding too many images

Tags: html, css, facebook

So I added a Facebook like button to my page, so far so good, but the thing is it keeps trying to be wider than I tell it to be and it spills over into my other content.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/tangoalphatango" data-send="false" data-width="600" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

If I add an overflow:hidden style and make the height 65px, that will chop off the extra friend image it's trying to add, that's a quick fix.

But, I'm trying to come up with a more elegant solution. I'm trying to make the Facebook like button do what I tell it to do which is be only 600px wide.

Comment: That may be tricky for a couple reasons. First, I believe it's against the Facebook terms of service to change its appearance. Second, they may have dead-end css properties (like "!important") to prevent you from changing it.

Comment: can you include so more code, the page, anything?  What it looks like when it spills over?

Comment: Here's the page itself: http://tangoalphatango.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that setting a height ( 65px in this case ) and setting the overflow to hidden is the solution I'll go with, with no other answers to choose from. I'm sure facebook generally doesn't appreciate the appearance of their like button being changed, but as long as it's overflowing into the remainder of my page I'll have to control it myself.